# (Beginner) Java program terminating for no reason

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently working on a hotel reservation practice program (I'm new to Java so I'm practicing by making random programs) For the life of me I can't figure out why the program terminates after I enter my number of guests, I wrote the program in Eclipse and I am compiling the program in Eclipse also. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
package text;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class HotelReservations {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Guests;
        String Reserved;

        int[] RoomsArray = new int[10];

        RoomsArray[0] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[1] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[2] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[3] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[4] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[5] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[6] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[7] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[8] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);
        RoomsArray[9] = (int) ((10 * Math.random()) - 1);   

        Date Date = new Date( );
            SimpleDateFormat ft = 
            new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE, d MMM yyyy 'at' hh:mm a!");

        System.out.println("Today's date is: " + ft.format(Date));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of guests:");
        Guests = in.nextInt();

        if (Guests > 8)
        {
            System.out.println("The maximum amount of guests allowed per room is 8. Please split groups of more than 8 into seperate rooms.");
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        else if (ArrayUtils.contains(RoomsArray, 0))
        {
            System.out.println("A room is available! The closest available room is: Room " + ArrayUtils.indexOf(RoomsArray, 0));
        } 
        else 
        { 
            System.out.println("Sorry, no rooms are available.");
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to reserve this room? (Yes/No)");
        Reserved = in.nextLine();

        if (Reserved.equals("Yes")) //here is where i changed it, now it will check yes/no
        {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It will print something and then immediately terminate, because *thats how the program is written*.

Comment: @1337 Can you explain why this is happening? I'm really new to Java.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416018/when-does-the-main-thread-stop-in-java If you still can't figure, I can elaborate here

Comment: Because there is no more code after printing the text. I guess you want to put in in a loop.

Comment: It will print something and then immediately terminate does it print "Would you like to reserve this room? (Yes/No)")

Comment: Spend some time reading the free-of-cost [online Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) provided by Oracle. In this case, the pages on [`while` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [`for` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [scanning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use same **scanner--in** for reading the input for integers and text

> It is not recommended to use same scanner for reading integers and
>   reading text input

use different scanners like scan1 and scan2
scan1 for integers
scan2 for next line as string

```
Scanner scan1= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(q.nextInt());
Scanner scan2= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(scan2.nextLine());
```