# Rxjava schedule wont run after last line

Tags: java, scheduler, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm new to RX and i don't know how the schedulers work. below is some code that never run `onComplete` . but if i put a `while(true)` loop at the end it works correctly. it seams the app will exit before running `new thread`.

why is this happening? and how to fix this issue?

```
Subscriber<String> subscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String o) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    };

    Observable.from(new String[]{"1", "2", "3","4"}).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `Thread.sleep(1000);` as the last statement if your program exits too early.

As to *why* this happens.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7416103/4096987) quotes:

> The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> ...
>
> All threads that are not daemon threads have died ...

Now if we look at `RxThreadFactory` that produces threads for `Schedulers`:

```java
public final class RxThreadFactory extends AtomicLong implements ThreadFactory {
    
    ...

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r, prefix + incrementAndGet());
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
}
```

So a more complex solution would be to use `Schedulers.from()` and pass in a custom `Executor` with your own `ThreadFactory` that produces non-daemon threads.

Comment: thanks! but not looking for just a working solution. looking for the right way. what if `newThread` is gonna take 5 seconds?

Comment: @sajad I've expanded my answer a little bit