# Java functions don't get executed in async

Tags: java

I have a problem. I have 4 classes: `classA`, `classB`, `classC` with all a function called `run()`. Now I am trying  to work with async, so what I want is the following:

1. In my `MainClass`, I call a async function from `classA` called `run()`
2. At the end of `classA.run()`, I call a `classB.run()`
3. In my MainClass, I want to wait until `classA` and `classB` have printed their line before running `classC.run()`.

Here is the code from every class. Class A:

```
public class classA {

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("CLASS A");

        new classB().run();

    }
    
}
```

Class B:

```
public class classB {
    
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("CLASS B");

    }

}
```

Class C:

```
public class classC {

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("CLASS C");

    }
    
}
```

And here is the code from my `MainClass`:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletableFuture<Void> testRun = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            new classA().run();
        });

        CompletableFuture<Void> test2Run = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(testRun).thenRunAsync(() -> {
            new classC().run();
        });

    }

}
```

But in my terminal I don't see any prints...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added full code, but it's not much, because I created a quick test project. The result of this program is no print in the command line, but for what I could understand is that prints that are executed async do get printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You are not waiting for the completion of your tasks. They run in async to your `main()` method, but they might not finish in time before the `main()` method do. This means you might not see the output from your tasks, depending if they were fast enough or not (see "race condition"). Use `get()` or `join()` to wait for the completion.
2. `CompletableFuture.completedFuture()` is not used to "wait" for another task to finish. You are building two tasks which run in parallel, which can results in output like `"A, C, B"`. If you want to "wait" for completion, you use something like `CompletableFuture.allOf()` or `CompletableFuture.anyOf()`, depending on what you need.

Comment: Yess!!! This did the trick. Just a little side question which is kinda related to this. My main program closes when the tasks are finished, but what if I open an API stream in a task... Then I want the program to never finish, but keep running? Where should I look for on google?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk If you want your application prevent from terminating, create a non-deamon thread. See other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416018/when-does-the-main-thread-stop-in-java/7416103#7416103

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into it! :)

Answer (score 1):

`testRun` and `testRun2` are executed by threads in `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`. 
 Threads in `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` terminate upon `main` thread's termination.

To wait for the asynchronous actions to complete, you should invoke `awaitTermination`.

So, the main method should look like:

```java
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> testRun = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            new classA().run();
        });

        CompletableFuture<Void> test2Run = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(testRun).thenRunAsync(() -> {
            new classC().run();
        });

       ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}
```

**Edit**:
A cleaner way to wait for all tasks to complete is:

```java
CompletableFuture.allOf(testRun, test2Run).join();
```