# Java Thread.sleep not working as expect in runnable implement

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to figure out how `Thread.sleep` works, so I create the following piece of code:

```java
 public static void main() {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Middle");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Before");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("After");
```

However, it only prints `Before` and `After` in the console and skips the `Middle`.

So I am wondering whether this Thread.sleep will break the Runnable part??

Comment: What do you mean "skips the `Middle`"? Your code should print out "Before", then "After", and then after one second it should print out "Middle".

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Output is exactly what Slaw said.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I got the point, the Junit kill the process before the thread t2 end

Comment: For future reference, please make sure you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. There is no reference to JUnit in your code or question and, as you've already discovered, that potentially changes things.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine output of your code is:

```
Before
After
Middle
```

If you want to print `Middle` before `After` you need to add `t2.join()` method call right after `t2.start()`. 
[Join method explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/joining-threads-in-java/).

Comment: Thanks vszholobov, I just realised the sleep is not blocking the process, but release the resource to other thread

Answer (score -1):

Use **join ()** to make your main thread wait till your thread (t2) execution finishes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Middle");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    System.out.println("Before");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
    t2.start();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println("After");
```

**Output:**
Before
Middle
After

Refer to this post to know about **join()** : [What does this thread join code mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956231/what-does-this-thread-join-code-mean)

Refer to this post to know about the **main thread**: [When does the main thread stop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416018/when-does-the-main-thread-stop-in-java)